# Hibernate & Geolatte Point Can not deserialize

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, gis, geospatial

I have a class with a Geolatte Point object that is throwing a can not deserialize error when it is retrieved from the database.

The environment is Java 18, Spring Boot 3.2 and Hibernate 6.2 and MySQL8.

The class containing the Point field is:

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@ToString
@Entity
@Data
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitalizer", "handler"})
@SequenceGenerator(name="check_seq", sequenceName = "CHECK_SEQ", initialValue = 100, allocationSize = 50)
@Table(name="CHECK")
public class Check {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = SEQUENCE, generator = "check_seq")
private Long id;

private Point<G2D> location;

// Getters and Setters
```

In application.properties I am initialising the database with

```
INSERT INTO HEALTH_CHECK (id, location, catch_date_time)
VALUES (6, ST_PointFromText('POINT(4.33 53.21)', 4326),'2023-06-01 13:00:00');
```

When I try to retrieve this object I get `Caused by: org.hibernate.type.SerializationException: could not deserialize`.

I then added the exact same point coordinates to the class in java (rather than through application.properties SQL) and I was able to set and retrieve the Check class without issue, i.e.:

```
Point<G2D> pnt=point(WGS84,g(4.33,53.21));
Check c = checkRepository.findById(5L).orElse(null);
c.setLocation(pnt);
checkRepository.save(hc);
// then evalulate expression shows entity with coords.
```

So the error appears to be related to the way that the coordinates are being applied to the database in MySQL by Hibernate/Geolatte.

I have compared the store working (Java set) vs MySQL SQL statement set values from the database column:

Working:
0xACED00057372002D6F72672E67656F6C617474652E67656F6D2E47656F6D657472792453657269616C697A6174696F6E50726F7879550F75859A8CA8920200015B00066275666665727400025B427870757200025B42ACF317F8060854E00200007870000000190101000020E610000052B81E85EB5111407B14AE47E19A4A40

Not Working:
0xE610000001010000007B14AE47E19A4A4052B81E85EB511140

I note that if I try SQL on the console to retrieve the non working point with `SELECT ST_AsText(location) FROM check WHERE id=5` I get the error `3055 Geometry byte string must be little endian'.

If this isn't a bug - what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I discovered that there was a error in my build.gradle that was causing the spatial dependacy not to be imported. My build.gradle was:

```
implementation group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-spatial', version: '6.2.6.Final', ext: 'pom'
```

It should not have the `pom` and should have just been:

```
implementation group: 'org.hibernate.orm', name: 'hibernate-spatial', version: '6.2.6.Final'
```

Everything works now.